# How to add dynamic c++ library to Android source?

Tags: android, c++

I need to add my native library to Android source for others applications can use it (call functions from this library in their code). I need to use library like embed without adding it to every project in that I want use it.  But i can't find information about this.

Please give me information how to do this. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, what you are trying to do is to run c/c++ code on Android. Am I right?

To be able to do that, you should use [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to build your native library, and then load it into java code.

You need to follow 4 simple steps to run native code on android, after installing ndk:

1) Create Java "wrapper" for your native code - for. eg. create class named `MyNatives` which will hold method declared with `native` keyword. This tells the compiler, that implementation of this method is done in native library. Create static initializer, which will load the library. eg:

```
    public class MyNatives { 
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("hello-jni"); 
        }
        public void native nativeMethod(int x); 
    }
```

2) Compile the code, and run tool called `javah` for your native class (there are some plugins for eclipsee which will do that for you, eg. [sequoyah](http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/))

```
    cd <your project path>
    mkdir jni
    javah -d jni -classpath bin/classes com.example.MyNatives
```

This will generate header in jni directory (all native code in android project should be inside this direcotry)

3) Add implementation of your method from generated header

4) Create makefile for android build system and build library. Makefile should be named `Android.mk`. It makes use of some specific variables and macros, for more info please see NDK documentation, eg:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    # your library name
    LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni

    # all source files
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

to buld library just call `ndk-build` from project root directory

For more info, please see Android NDK documentation. Hope it helped a little.

Comment: Yes, I want to run c++ code on Android. Thanks for your answer, but as I understand in this case (using Android NDK) I need to do this (your instruction) for any application if I want to use library in that app. But I need to add library in Android OS (in Android source code and compile it) to use this library in any application like embed without adding library to every project.
Is it possibly?

Comment: Each Android application runs essentially in a sandbox. System libraries are shared, but applications can't see eachothers content.

There is, apparently, a way of getting specific applications to share the same sandbox (run as the same user ID), but I'll need to go investigate this.

Comment: I want to add new system library to Android source for using in any application

Comment: Well, I am not sure if this is possible without compiling android from source and creating new kernel for it.

Another solutions which comes to my mind is to create android library project and create inside it a wrapper for your native library. Then, you can include it as library in every application which should use it.

Comment: I understand. I have Android source and I want to compile it with my library. But I don't know exactly where put my library for using it as  other embed native Android library

Comment: I suspect this will help http://discuz-android.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/add-new-component-into-open-source.html